# POSTa Request with rest assured api using XML Payload

Tags: rest

I am in need of one requirement.I want to POST a request using Rest Assured API using XML payload,I did not get any where how to set the body using XML. any one please tell me how I can achieve this.

I have one table customers with 5 fileds,name,id,address,email and phone number.My URL to post the request is something like
"http://com.myproject.app:8080/MyApp/SchmaName/customers".Please any one help me out.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The above should work, here it is again in a slightly different version with your example...

```
Response response = given().
contentType("application/xml").
body(myXML).
when().
post("http://com.myproject.app:8080/MyApp/SchmaName/customers");
```

myXML would be the xml you want to send (5 fields; name,id,address,email and phone number). After that you can pull the result from response.

Answer (score 0):

You can just post in the request body as a String, InputStream, byte[] or a Java object (that will be serialized to XML using JAXB). For example:

```
String myXML = ..
given().contentType(ContentType.XML).body(myXML).when().post("/x").then(). ..
```